# Implicit declaration of function 'UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM' is invalid in C99

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

In Swift and Objective c Hybrid project(link https://github.com/shohagHub/Constants) I have an Objective C file Constants.h

Where I Declare a macro `#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)`

When I returned this macro from a method

```
-(BOOL)isIphone{
    return IS_IPHONE;
}
```

The Following build error occurs 
"**Implicit declaration of function 'UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM' is invalid in C99**"

How Can I remove this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add to your Constants.h
 `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`
it will work

Answer (score 1):

Does your file import UIKit? No, it doesn't. Your *Constants.h* file imports Foundation, not UIKit. Import UIKit instead and your code will compile.

But also note: the docs on `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` expicitly say:

> If your app runs in iOS 3.2 and later, use userInterfaceIdiom instead.

So here's a better rewrite of your entire *Constants.h* file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Constants : NSObject
#define IS_IPHONE ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
-(BOOL)isIphone;
@end
```